# How i execute datetime between two datetimes

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

I would like to generate a timestamp between each StartDate:StartTime and EndDate:EndTime.

such as

```
StartDate 2019-01-01 ,StartTime 01:00:00 --- only appear hour (2019-01-01 ,01)
 
EndDate 2019-01-11 ,EndTime 1:00:00.---only appear hour (2019-01-11 ,01)
```

and show Date and Time both in one column in the table

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pandas as pd
def generate_date_list(from_date, to_date):
    list_of_dates = []
    start = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    step = timedelta(days=1)
    while start <= end:
        list_of_dates.append(start.date())
        start += step
    
    dt = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for i in list_of_dates]
    return {"Date_Time": dt}

date_time_list = generate_date_list("2019-01-01", "2019-01-11")
df = pd.DataFrame(date_time_list)

print(df)

#You can use df.to_sql() to insert on table.
```

Comment: Code only answers are not as useful as if they are enriched by explanations. Please consider adding some text to explain your code, the choices you made and why.

Comment: thank you dear Tanmay Shrivastava , if i want to  create 24 hour per every day what i do ? @Tanmay Shrivastava

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pandas date_range function

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='2009-01-01 01:00:00', end='2009-01-11 00:00:00',freq='H')
for date in dates:
    print(date)
```

This will print all datetimes between starttime and endtime

Comment: Thank you dear josephthomaa.